# change database location of multiple crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using Crystal reports 9.2.0.448. I have created 50+ crystal reports in my machine. And set database location as **local_sql_server_name.database_name**. Now, I want to install all reports in my client's machine. So definitely, the sql server name is changed. So I have to set database location of all crystal reports manually. So I want to know that ***is there any way to change database location automatically?***

I also tried the **Universal Data Link (.udl)** File. I set database location from that file. But if I modify .udl file then it does not affect to crystal reports.

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub RecurseAndRemap(ByVal CR As Engine.ReportDocument)
        For Each DSC As CrystalDecisions.Shared.IConnectionInfo In CR.DataSourceConnections
            DSC.SetLogon("YourUserName", "YourPassword")
            DSC.SetConnection("YouServerName", "YourDatabaseName", False)
        Next

        CR.SetDatabaseLogon("YourUserName", "YourPassword")

        For Each Table As Engine.Table In CR.Database.Tables
            Table.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = "YourUserName"
            Table.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = "YourPassword"
        Next

        If Not CR.IsSubreport Then
            For Each SR As Engine.ReportDocument In CR.Subreports
                RecurseAndRemap(SR)
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Does this save the updated server in the actual Crystal Report or just in the in memory ReportDocument object?

Comment: just in memory. do you need to save the updated server in crystal report or do you want only to change the connection at run time ?

Comment: @AsifGhafoor I want to save the updated server in crystal reports. This is my actual problem.

Comment: That I've never had luck with.  I've only been able to update it at runtime.